# How to modify this pinescript v5 code to plot dotted line?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to plot dotted line. How can I modify the code below to plot dotted line?

```
plot(series=test_series,color=Color,linewidth=3,title="testplot")
```

I am using pinescript 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot` does not have a dotted style.

> ***style (input plot_style)*** Type of plot. Possible values are:
> `plot.style_line`, `plot.style_stepline`, `plot.style_stepline_diamond`,
> `plot.style_histogram`, `plot.style_cross`, `plot.style_area`,
> `plot.style_columns`, `plot.style_circles`, `plot.style_linebr`,
> `plot.style_areabr`. Default value is `plot.style_line`.

You can try `plot.style_circles` for a similar effect.

Or use `line` which has a dotted style.

> ***style (series string)*** Line style. Possible values: `line.style_solid`,
> `line.style_dotted`, `line.style_dashed`, `line.style_arrow_left`,
> `line.style_arrow_right`, `line.style_arrow_both`.